# How to separate business logic to classes from windows form in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm working within C# and visual studio and have made a Windows Form (`MainForm`) - it has a good amount of buttons that work through a number of process'.

Currently - it actually works fine, I just wanted to 'make it work'. However, all my code lies in the `MainForm.cs` file and I believe that is bad practice. I've got a lot of methods in there that I feel would be better placed in appropriate classes.

I have gathered through reading that `buttonClick` events should live in the Form class, but then should hand off the rest of the work to classes for which the buttons exist (i.e. if a button says to 'backup pictures', I should have a Pictures class with a 'backup' method).

Is there a good way in visual studio to go about doing that?

Are there any helpers to take existing methods and put them into their own classes?

Comment: How is this a Visual Studio question? Please only use the Visual Studio tag for questions about the tool itself, not for general programming questions.

Comment: In these situations, I always just create my classes and copy/paste/tweak the code out of the UI and into my new classes manually.  I can't really imagine what kind of tools Visual Studio could have provided to make it any easier - for me it's usually just kind of a down-and-dirty chore to do this stuff.

Comment: Take a look at [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/), it provides advanced refactoring utilities, for example to move a method to its own file. ReSharper -> Refactor -> Move.

Comment: Awesome suggestion @GeorgPatscheider! Thanks! Joe, I appreciate your input, too. I'm not sure how common it is to just 'code it to work' then move the logic around. I'm new to C# and visual studio - mostly just PHP frameworks - so windows forms is a learning curve - I appreciate the feedback~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that `Events` and `Event Handlers` should exist in the `Form` while all data manipulation should be handled in `classes` called by the `Handler`.  Unfortunately, there's no tool that magically splits these out for you, as there is no real way to automate what needs a class and what is better left inline.

You should roll through the code and establish the classes you will need *first*.  Go ahead and stub them out by creating `New` `Class` files with "Add New".  They don't need any code in them at all yet. Now, go to your `event` handlers in your Form and identify groups of things that should be in functions. For a (really cheap) example:

```
//old code
public void myEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string myDrink = myDrinkOfChoice.Text; //these are textbox controls
   string myFood = myFoodOfChoice.Text;
   LabelResult.Text = "I like " + myDrink + " & " + myFood";
}
```

Becomes:

```
//new code
public void myEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
   LabelResult.Text = Order.Preference(myDrinkOfChoice.Text, myFoodOfChoice.Text);
}
```

You'll get the red squiggly of an error under `Order.Preference`, even if you've made an "Order" class file. You'll need to make `Order`into a class, but you don't need to stub out `Preference`, as VS can do this for you. Click on the error resolution dynamic menu button that appears when you mouse over the error and tell VS to stub the code in your `Order` class. When you open `Order` again, you'll see:

```
public static class Order
{
   public static string Preference(string myDrink, string myFood)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

All you have to do from here is paste in the code that was in the `Form` and return the value.

```
 public static class Order
    {
       public static string Preference(string myDrink, string myFood)
       {
         return "I like " + myDrink + " & " + myFood";
       }
    }
```

Letting VS stub out what you need is probably the fastest way to do what you're trying to do, while not sacrificing reliability. If you create the class files ahead of time, you can just make up the method names and signatures as you go through the `event` handlers in your `Form` and let VS stub out the methods for you.

Comment: Great idea on using the red squiggles to help create the methods in the classes quickly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have got this problem earlier in my previous project, Here is how to sort out this.

1. If you need to calls to COM API you need to add some DLL that is also part of WinForms project, otherwise better to call them from WinForms project.
2. You can take out everything but not anything that is related to UI part. If you need to do that again you need to add those dll to the class library.

if you reference any different version in class library and different in project you will break the project.

so it's better to take out everything and leave the UI, COM calls, everything will work fine this way.